# Should I add the .metadata folder to the source control?

Tags: eclipse

I've created a project using PyDev plugin for Eclipse. Now I need to add necessary files to the repository and unnecessary files to the ignore list. What should I do with the .metadata folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.metadata` stores your workspace settings (not the project settings). I'm not sure what exactly it contains but I think it has many settings about your personal preferences or that are local to your PC, so it may not be a good idea to add it if you're going to work in a team.

Sadly enough, the project related metadata (in `.project` and `.settings`) is a mix of local/personal data and data that is the same for everyone, and it's hard to split that up.